# Simular Cambio de pagina

Tags: android

estoy mirando de hacer una aplicación que simule una tarjeta de felicitaciones para un cumpleaños, y no se como hacer para que al apretar un botón parezca que se cambia de página. 
Como podría hacerlo? estoy usando android studio.

Gracia de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Que has hecho hasta ahora?

Comment: Solo tengo un SplashScreen, y tengo preparados los audios para la aplicación, a parte de eso nada ya que no se como se hace para hacer este cambio de pagina.

Comment: Es difícil ayudarte si no tienes nada. Lo que quieres lograr lo puedes hacer con un [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html).

Comment: Ok ahora me pondré a ver si consigo utilizar bien el ViewPager, gracias por responder.

Comment: Cuando tengas una duda de como utilizar el ViewPager no dudes en publicar una pregunta, de seguro en esa si podremos ayudarte.

Comment: El viewPager lo puedes crear con sus respectivos fragmentos claramente de forma fácil, AS te da la opción de crear uno solo con crear una nuevo layout, ten presente aquello.

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info): Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.